# Verify the type of a lambda expression

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

I need to verify the type for the lambda expression:
[image: lambdaexp]

My method gives me: 
[image: result]

Im trying to define it in Haskell (on Hugs) like this:

```
h= \f x -> f (f x)
```

When i call the :type comamnd it gives me:

```
(a -> a) -> a -> a
```

Is mi function correctly defined in Haskell?, or my method gives me a wrong result?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that `f` gets called with both `x` and `f x` as its argument—this immediately means that the type of `x` and the type of `f x` must be the same[1]. Carrying this argument onward, we see that since `x` is the input to `f` and `f x` is the output of `f`, the input and output of `f` must be the same[2].

Finally, we examine the lambda term

```
\f x -> f (f x)
```

it has two inputs, `f` (a function) and `x`, and it returns whatever the return type of `f` is[3]. Putting all of this information together we have

```
(a -> b) -> c -> d

where:

  b ~ c        by [1]
  a ~ b        by [2]
  d ~ b        by [3]
```

thus the type which Haskell inferred is correct

```
h :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
h f x = f (f x)
```

Comment: It's important to note also that because of associativity of the `->` notation for types, this is the same as `(a -> a) -> (a -> a)` - this was probably part of OP's confusion.

Answer (score 3):

The type `(a -> b) -> (c -> d)` is equivalent to`(a -> b) -> c -> d` in haskells type system. You also need to consider, if x had type a, and `f x` has type b, then f has type `a -> b`. So let `y = f x`. So what is the type of `f y === f (f x)`?

Answer (score 2):

Your Haskell command is fine.

Your type inference is incorrect though. The type of the `x` argument should unify with the type of the input to `f`, since you call `f x`, then the input type of `f` should unify with the output type of `f` since you call `f` on the result `(f x)`.